# Cannot get AngularJS to work in Google Spreadsheet Sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-apps-script, sidebar

I am using a google spreadsheet to get data from a form (in this case, the google sheets sidebar) and send the data back to my spreadsheet to populate the sheet. I want to have a variable number of fields in my form, and I have created an HTML file using AngularJS to do so. Below is my file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Objectives</title>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.3.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">

    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

        myApp.controller('cerebroController', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.objectives = 5;
            $scope.keyResults = 2;
            $scope.getNumber = function (n) {
                console.log(n);
                var retArr = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    retArr[i] = i;
                }
                return retArr;
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script src="sheetUpdate.gs"></script>
</head>
<body ng-App="myApp">
<div ng-controller="cerebroController" class="main">
    <select name="numObjs" ng-model="objectives">
        <option ng-repeat="i in getNumber(10)" value="{{$index+1}}">{{$index+1}}</option>
    </select>
    <ul ng-repeat="i in getNumber(objectives)">
        <h3>Objective {{$index+1}} Name</h3>
        <input type="text" value="" class="keys">
        <select name="numObjs" ng-model="keyResults">
            <option ng-repeat="i in getNumber(10)" value="{{$index+1}}">{{$index+1}}</option>
        </select>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <ul ng-repeat="i in getNumber(keyResults)">
            <br>
            <p>Key Result {{$index + 1}}</p>
            <input id="route" type="text" value="" class="form-control">
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is how I create the sidebar in GS:

```
function showSidebar()
{

  var htm = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('cerebro.html').setTitle('Generate Lines').setWidth(300);
  htm.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  ui.showSidebar(htm);

};
```

But when I load up the sidebar, the fields are not dynamically generated and where I have double curly braces for Angular, the literal string is printed, such as "{{$index+1}}". Does anyone know how I can get Angular to work with my sidebar?